# Extract dataframe from an existing sorted pandas dataframe group by group?

Tags: python, pandas

It might not be clear from the title but I want to do something like this using a sorted pandas dataframe:

suppose the dataframe is something like this:

```
name    amount

abc     25

abc     45

xyz     20

xyz     50

xyz     55
```

Now what I want to do is do a groupby on this dataframe by names.

And then loop over the groups one by one,and do some processing on them.

That is on first loop I would want to store the group abc into another intermediate dataframe process it and so on:

so while looping:

that is first iteration:

intermediate dataframe should have

```
name amount

abc 25

abc 45
```

then next iteration:

intermediate dataframe should have

```
name amount

xyz 20

xyz 50

xyz 55
```

So, I want to do this. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need loop `DataFrameGroupBy` object:

```
for idx, df in df.groupby('name'):
    print (df)
  name  amount
0  abc      25
1  abc      45
  name  amount
2  xyz      20
3  xyz      50
4  xyz      55
```

If need some processing use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    print (x)

df = df.groupby('name').apply(f)
print (df)
```

Also check [flexible apply in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply).